# How does TeX handle \else and \fi in conditionals?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

I have seen packages using

```
\def\afterelse#1\else#2\fi{\fi#1}
```

which TeX seems happy to accept. But on taking the first branch, isn't TeX expecting `\else` instead of `\fi`? That is, isn't the following the correct syntax for the first fork? This too is accepted by TeX.

```
\def\afterelse#1\else#2\fi{\else#1}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to Egreg. Tracing `\if`s shows what is happening.

```
\def\loggingallstuff{%
  \tracinggroups\@ne\tracingifs\@ne\loggingall\tracingassigns\@ne
}

\def\afterelse#1\else#2\fi{\fi#1}

{\loggingallstuff
  %\edef\x{\iftrue\afterelse T\else F\fi}
  \edef\x{\iftrue T\else F\fi}
%  \edef\x{\iffalse T\else F\fi}
}

% \iftrue
{\edef}
{\iftrue: (level 1) entered on line 23}
{true}
{\else: \iftrue (level 1) entered on line 23}
{\fi: \iftrue (level 1) entered on line 23}
{changing \x=undefined}
{into \x=macro:->T}

% \iffalse:
{\edef}
{\iffalse: (level 1) entered on line 24}
{false}
{\else: \iffalse (level 1) entered on line 24}
{\fi: \iffalse (level 1) entered on line 24}
{changing \x=undefined}
{into \x=macro:->F}
```

Here is one case I find interesting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter

\def\pgfkeysafterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}
%\def\pgfkeysafterelsei#1\else#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\pgfkeysafterelsei#1\else#2\fi{\else#1} % wrong but gives no error.

\def\pgfkeysifkeydef#1#2#3{%
  \ifcsname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\endcsname
    \pgfkeysafterelsei{#2}\else\pgfkeysafterfi{#3}\fi
}
\pgfkeys{%
  /handlers/.if definable/.code 2 args={
    \pgfkeysifkeydef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{%
      \@latexerr{Oops, key '\pgfkeyscurrentpath' already exists}
        {You aren't in trouble here!}%
    }{%
      \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.default=#1,\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=#2}%
    }%
  }%
}
\pgfkeys{
  /fam/.is family,/fam/.cd,
  keya/.if definable=\relax\@empty,
  keya/.if definable=\@empty{\def\x##1{##1*#1}},
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another odd point with conditionals is that `\iftrue\else\or\fi` is legal and writes `{\or: \iftrue (level 1) ...}` to the log when tracing ifs.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: But does it have any application? `\iffalse\def\x{T}\else\def\x{F}\or\fi` gives `extra \or`.

Comment: I can't think of an application right now, but there may be weird cases where it is useful.  Say that you have a macro `\def\foo#1{\ifx?#1abc\else def\fi}` (meant to give `abc` when `#1` is `?` and `def` otherwise).  Giving it `?\else` as an argument will produce no output.  I've had somewhat similar situations within `l3fp`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's use `\iftrue` and `\iffalse` for testing what happens, assuming the definition

```
\def\afterelse#1\else#2\fi{\fi#1}
```

### `\iftrue`

```
\iftrue\afterelse T\else F\fi
```

becomes

```
\afterelse T\else F\fi
```

and the next expansion gives

```
\fi T
```

### `\iffalse`

```
\iffalse\afterelse T\else F\fi
```

becomes

```
F\fi
```

and the expansion of `\fi` is empty.

---

The important thing is that when the "true" branch is taken, only the test is removed, while everything up to and including `\else` is removed when the "false" branch is taken. This can be seen in the following interactive session:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
**\relax

*\toks0=\expandafter{\iftrue T\else F\fi}         

*\showthe\toks0
> T\else F\fi .
<*> \showthe\toks0

? 

*\toks0=\expandafter{\iffalse T\else F\fi}

*\showthe\toks0
> F\fi .
<*> \showthe\toks0
```

---

The code

```
\def\afterelse#1\else#2\fi{\else#1}
```

is not correct, as shown by the following interactive session

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
**\relax

*\def\afterelse#1\else#2\fi{\else#1}

*\iftrue\afterelse T\else F\fi

*
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*\bye
! Incomplete \iftrue; all text was ignored after line 0.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<to be read again> 
                   \bye 
<*> \bye
```

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, when TeX sees `\else`, it removes everything up to the corresponding `\fi`?

Comment: @tohecz Yes, that's the effect of the expansion of `\else`.