# How are parameter tokens (#1,#2,...,#9) processed?

Tags: token-lists, arguments

I wonder how the TeX token muncher processes **parameter arguments**. It seems that parameter arguments are sent token by token. Is this true?

Consider the following code based on [wipet's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215569/13552) used to store an "array":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex

\newcount\itemidx
\def\setarray#1#2{\itemidx=0 \edef\tmp{\string#1}\setarrayItem#2\end}
\def\setarrayItem#1{\advance\itemidx by1
   \ifx\end#1\else
      \expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\the\itemidx\endcsname{#1}%
      \expandafter\setarrayItem\fi
}
\def\getarray[#1]#2{\csname data:\string#2:#1\endcsname}

\setarray\groups{{one}{two}{three}}
\setarray\nogroups{one two three}

\begin{document}
\null
\getarray[1]\groups

\getarray[1]\nogroups
\end{document}
```

1. I would like to understand why `\getarray[1]\groups` and `\getarray[1]\nogroups` yield different results.
2. Is the recursive line `\expandafter\setarrayItem\fi` a kind of implicit loop for parameter token munching?
3. Why does putting `\show#1` at the beginning of the `\setarray` definition yield `o` and not `{one}` or `{one} {two} {three}`. It would seem category codes 1 and 2 are ignored when processing parameter arguments, but do make a difference in `\groups` and `\nogroups`.

---

## Notes

The term parameter token is mentioned in the TeX Book on p.203

> TEX also recognizes “parameter tokens,” denoted here by #1 to #9. Parameter tokens can appear only in token lists for macros.

Comment: I think you are looking for the concept of _balanced text_

Comment: Parameter tokens `#1` and so on are only relevant at the time a macro definition is performed, not when the macro is expanded. I don't think that `\getarray[1]\groups` can give different results, so please fix the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tex macros have two kinds of argument, delimited and non delimited, for a non delimited argument the argument is either a single token, or if the token is an explicit brace (a character of catcode 1) then the argument is all the balanced text up to the matching `}` (character of catcode 2) in the latter case the braces are not passed as part of the argument. So if you have

```
\def\xxx#1{...#1...}
```

Then after `\xxx Z`  then `#1` will be the single token `Z` but after `\xxx {ab{c}}` it will be the 5 tokens `ab{c}`

Delimited arguments are similar but match all tokens up to a specified sequence of tokens (`]` in your example above)  after

```
\def\yyy#1@?@{...#1...}
```

then after `\yyy abc @?@` then `#1` is the 4 tokens `abc`  and the same tokens are passed if the input is `\yyy {abc }@?@` as if a delimited argument would consist just of a brace group, the outer level of braces is stripped.

`\show` only ever shows a single token so `\show #1` if `#1` is `one` is the same as `\show one` which will show `o` and typeset `ne`

---

The question

> Is the recursive line `\expandafter\setarrayItem\fi` a kind of implicit loop for parameter token munching?

isn't particularly related to parameters other than the `\fi` closes the `\ifx\end#1` test which means that if `#1` was not end, the macro recursively calls itself in this branch, the branch when `#1` is `\end` is empty, so stopping the iteration.

Comment: As you said *it will be the 5 tokens ab{c}*, but *the braces are not passed as part of the argument* here, correct? I thought the `{c}` would just be a single "balanced text" argument. Your examples do not make it particularly clear about what is "delimited" and "non-delimited". And when you say branch, you mean argument of "{balanced text}"?

Comment: @macmadness86 if `{c}` ever gets passed as an argument it would be that but at the point it is passed in the `{` and `}` are just tokens, tex for example doesn't look if it is  `a\mbox{c]`  or `ab{\small}` where in the first case the `{}` will eventually delimit a macro argument, and in the second they will not but be treated after macro expansion to form a group to scope the effects of `\small`.

Comment: @macmadness86 braces are of course passed as part of the argument apart from the outermost pair used to delimit the argument. otherwise if you put `\mbox{\textbf{zz}}` it doesn't drop all braces while passing `#1` to `\mbox` and become  equivalent `\mbox{\textbf zz}`

Answer (score 10):

Parameter tokens `#1` to `#9` are only relevant at macro definition time, so you're being misled when thinking to them.

The macro `\setarray` has two *undelimited* arguments (because the parameter token are not separated from each other by anything). This means that TeX will look for two arguments when expanding `\setarray`.

When looking for an undelimited argument (again, the “delimited” or “undelimited” only refers to how the macro has been defined), TeX skips space tokens until finding a nonspace one. There are two cases:

1. the nonspace token is not a `<left brace>`
2. the nonspace token is a `<left brace>`

(meaning an *explicit* `{` or any other token with category code 1, but let's not complicate things).

In the first case, the nonspace token is substituted for the corresponding parameter in the replacement text. In the second case, TeX continues scanning the input looking for the matching `<right brace>` (so keeping track of brace nesting). When it has found it, it strips off those outer braces and substitutes the whole set of absorbed tokens in place of the corresponding parameter.

Thus, with `\def\foo#1#2{-#1-#2-}`, the calls

```
\foo\bar\x
\foo\bar{abc}
\foo{abc}\bar
\foo{abc}{def}
```

will result in delivering, respectively,

```
-\bar-\x-
-\bar-abc-
-abc-\bar-
-abc-def-
```

to the main token list for further processing.

Let's see what `\setarray\groups{{one}{two}{three}}` does; by the rules above, `#1` is replaced with `\groups` and `#2` by `{one}{two}{three}`, so the new token list will be

```
\itemidx=0 \edef\tmp{\string\groups}\setarrayItem{one}{two}{three}\end
```

The two assignments are performed and we remain with

```
\setarrayItem{one}{two}{three}\end
```

According to its definition, `\setarrayItem` has one argument; the rules above say it's `{one}` (but the braces will be stripped off), so we get

```
\advance\itemidx by1
   \ifx\end one\else
      \expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\the\itemidx\endcsname{one}%
      \expandafter\setarrayItem\fi
{two}{three}\end
```

(line breaks and `%` don't really make sense in token lists, I use them just for clarity). The assignment is performed and disappears (`\itemidx` will contain the value 1). Then the `\ifx` test is performed, comparing `\end` with `o`; since the two tokens are different, the tokens up to `\else` are swallowed, so we remain with

```
\expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\the\itemidx\endcsname{one}%
\expandafter\setarrayItem\fi
{two}{three}\end
```

OK, `\expandafter` acts on `\csname` which will build a symbolic token; we'll be left with

```
\def\data:\groups:1{one}\expandafter\setarrayItem\fi{two}{three}\end
```

where, remember, `\data:\groups:1` is a single token. The definition is performed and we're left with

```
\expandafter\setarrayItem\fi{two}{three}\end
```

Here `\expandafter` expands `\fi` (that leaves nothing), so we obtain

```
\setarrayItem{two}{three}\end
```

and the same as before will be repeated causing the definition of `\data:\groups:2` and `\data:\groups:3`. At the next iteration, we'll be left with

```
\setarrayItem\end
```

and now we'll have

```
\advance\itemidx by1
   \ifx\end\end\else
      \expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\the\itemidx\endcsname{\end}%
      \expandafter\setarrayItem\fi
```

The counter is advanced, then `\end` is compared to `\end`: oh, the test returns true! So nothing is removed except the test tokens, so we remain with

```
\else
\expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\the\itemidx\endcsname{\end}%
\expandafter\setarrayItem\fi
```

What's the expansion of `\else`? It consists in swallowing everything up to the matching `\fi` and make everything found disappear. End of the recursion. To recapitulate, we have defined three macros (with complicated names.

In the case of

```
\setarray\nogroups{one two three}
```

the routine will do the definitions

```
\def\data:\nogroups:1{o}
\def\data:\nogroups:2{n}
\def\data:\nogroups:3{e}
\def\data:\nogroups:4{t}
\def\data:\nogroups:5{w}
\def\data:\nogroups:6{o}
\def\data:\nogroups:7{t}
\def\data:\nogroups:8{h}
\def\data:\nogroups:9{r}
\def\data:\nogroups:10{e}
\def\data:\nogroups:11{e}
```

because the spaces between `e` and `t` and between `o` and `t` will be ignored because of the rule by which undelimited arguments are looked for.

The macro `\getarray[1]\groups` will build the control sequence named

```
\data:\groups:1
```

and its expansion will deliver `one`; with `\getarray[1]\nogroups`, the control sequence

```
\data:\nogroups:1
```

is built and its expansion delivers `o`.

---

Now you should compare all of the above with this rough implementation in `expl3`, where the code is almost self-explaining (but less fun):

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \setarray #1 #2
 {
  \tl_clear_new:N #1
  \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \getarray [#1] #2
 {
  \tl_item:Nn #2 #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Not that I recommend the syntax `\getarray[1]\groups`, as the square brackets seem extraneous to the context. This even allows, out of the box, to call `\getarray[-1]\groups` to access the last item in the array.

Oh, and

```
\setarray\foo{{\textbf{a}}{\textit{a}}{\textsf{a}}}

\edef\baz{\getarray[1]\foo}
```

would work and store `\textbf{a}` in `\baz`. Try it with the (admittedly clever) code by wipet.

Comment: Why the `\expandafter` is in `\expandafter\setarrayItem\fi{two}{three}\end` was critical to my understanding. I like how you showed the resulting tokens for each step. Educational, useful, and fascinating! Thank you. For reference, I found the trace of `\if` useful here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68662/how-does-tex-handle-else-and-fi-in-conditionals